# How to insert one or more character in the middle of a string using python?

Tags: python, regex, permutation

I wanted to list all the associative operation possible for an n-elements group. For example, when n=3, I want it to print:

```py
a*(a*a)  =  (a*a)*a
a*(a*b)  =  (a*a)*b
a*(a*c)  =  (a*a)*c
... 24 more lines
```

Now, my best attempt to produce these is the following python3 code.

```py
import itertools as it

def permutation_func(str_, rep):
  chars = list(str_)
  results = []
  for tuple_ in it.product(chars, repeat = rep):
    i = ''.join(tuple_)
    results.append(i)
  return results
 
my_list = permutation_func('abc', 3)

for i in my_list:
    print(i, " = ", i)
```

However, the output I am getting is:

```
aaa  =  aaa
aab  =  aab
aac  =  aac
... and 24 more lines
```

I think I am on the right track. But I cannot figure it out how to transform `aaa = aaa` to `a*(a*a) = (a*a)*a` which is basically I need to insert the `*` sign and the parentheses multiple times inside the text.

I have tried googling and I found that I need regular expressions to do this. However, I never used regular expression. So I am looking for an alternative that does not use regular expression. I don't even know whether it is possible without regular expression. If it is not, let me know please.

Comment: Please add some examples for n=4 or more? I imagine that parentheses in those cases could be in multiple set e.g `(a * b * c) * d` or `(a * b) * (c * d)` or `a * (b * c) * d` or `a * (b * c * d)` and all of those are equal.

Comment: Hi @AKS your question is more of an algebra question. Anyways, I am afraid you got it wrong. For n=4, the first 3 lines would be the same as n=3 but the fourth line would be a* (a * d) =(a * a) * d. Here it is a binary operation and the associativity of binary operation is defined like this. For example, your (a*b*c) doesn't make any sense unless it is a trinary operator and it is your notation to express like this. Otherwise, the difference between n=3 and n=4 would be that n=4 would have 64 lines not 27.

Comment: I see, so is it safe to say that irrespective of how many elements are there in the string say `abc` or `abcd`, you are always generating a permutation of 3 characters?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. That is what associativity is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments the following should work

```
for c1, c2, c3 in itertools.product('abc', repeat=3):
    print(f'({c1}*{c2})*{c3} = {c1}*({c2}*{c3})')
```

It prints:

```
(a*a)*a = a*(a*a)
(a*a)*b = a*(a*b)
(a*a)*c = a*(a*c)
... 24 more
```

If you replace the string with `abcd`, it will generate 64 entries.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunatelly, strings in Python are not mutable objects - so you just can insert a character in a position. (And regular expressions would not help - they have a fancy mechanism for replacing some text, and while it would be possible to do the insertions you want with a call to `re.sub`, figuring out the correct regexp and a callback function to do this would not be worth it)

On the other hand, Python's `list`s are sequences that can be arbitrarily changed. And fortunately, there is a simple mechanism to convert strings to lists and back. Once you have a list, you can either use the `.insert` method, or slice assignment to insert your values:

```
a = "aaa"
b = list(a)
b.insert(1, "*")
b.insert(2, "(")
b.insert(4, "*")
b.insert(6,")")
c = "".join(b)
```

Given what you intend to do, maybe this is not the most practical way to do it - you probably should have a function that will get a sequence of tokens as input (which can be a list, or a string with one-letter tokens), and instructions on how to group and an interpolating character, and then return it as a string:

```
def group_tokens(tokens, start, end, join="*"):
    output = ""
    for index, token in enumerate(tokens):
        if index != 0:
            output += join
        if index == start:
            output += "("
        elif index == end:
            output += ")"
        output += token
    if end >= len(tokens):
        output += ")"
    return output
```

Comment: The function group_tokens() is what I exactly wanted. I used it at the end of my code and it solved my problem. This code bit even helped me to produce more general output for n=4 and more. Thanks.

Comment: `my_list = permutation_func('abc', 3)

for i in my_list:
 i1 = group_tokens(i,1,3)
 i2 = group_tokens(i,0,2)
 i2 = i2.replace("*)",")*")
 print(i1, " = ", i2)`
This what gives the exact solution